# return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] warning in C

Tags: c, gcc, incompatibility

when I'm calling this function

```
 4 char *file_reader(FILE *fp, char *file_name, const char *mode) {
  5     char *buffer;
  6     fp = fopen(file_name, mode);
  7 
  8     if (fp != NULL) {
  9         fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
 10         long s = ftell(fp);
 11         rewind(fp);
 12         buffer = malloc(s);
 13         if (buffer != NULL) {
 14             fread(buffer, s, 1, fp);
 15             fclose(fp);
 16             fp = NULL;
 17         }
 18         if (fp != NULL)
 19             fclose(fp);
 20     } else {
 21         printf("No such file.\n");
 22         return "ERR";
 23     }
 24     return buffer;
 25 }
```

by

```
 char *file_content = file_reader(fp, input_file, "r");
```

gcc kept complaining `return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`, but I dont see any incompatible pointer type. Anyone has any idea on that, thank you.

Comment: Did you put the prototype before the call ?

Comment: Btw, the C standard says: `Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the initial shift state.`

Comment: Don't return the address of a string literal, even in the error case, this will cause you head aches later on. String literals are not modifiable but unfortunately typed `char[]` and not `char const[]`. You are loosing that information when returning that from the function. A better convention would be to just return `0`.

Comment: 1. Always use the `-Wall` when invoking the compiler; gcc will warn you of various problems with your code, such as the missing prototype mentioned by cnicutar. 2. return `strdup("ERR")` in the error case, so that the program doesn't crash when the caller frees the returned file content.

Answer (score 0):

Works. Compiled it with `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11`.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
FILE* fp;
char* input_file = "asdf.txt";
char *file_reader(FILE *fp, char *file_name, const char *mode) {
    char *buffer;
    fp = fopen(file_name, mode);
    if (fp != NULL) {
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
        long s = ftell(fp);
        rewind(fp);
        buffer = malloc(s);
        if (buffer != NULL) {
            fread(buffer, s, 1, fp);
            fclose(fp);
            fp = NULL;
        }
        if (fp != NULL)
            fclose(fp);
    } else {
        printf("No such file.\n");
        return "ERR";
    }
    return buffer;
}
int main() {
    char *file_content = file_reader(fp, input_file, "r");
    printf("%s\n", file_content);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a prototype for file_reader() is missing at the point where you make the call. Without a prototype, `int` is assumed as the return type of functions.

To solve this, you should either put a prototype for the function in a header and then include that, or manually write a prototype before you make the call. So you need this:

```
char *file_reader(FILE *fp, char *file_name, const char *mode);
```

Another issue with file_reader() is that you forgot to make its `file_name` parameter `const`.

Answer (score 0):

The "incompatible pointer type" is the one to the *constant* string "ERR"